# Do I have better performances on a VPS or shared hosting offers?

Tags: laravel, performance, web, hosting, laradock

Its about a long time that I'm asking my self this question but I've never had a truly response. Most of time people tell that it depend on the language and the usage of the website.

From now I'm using a sharing hosting from OVH but I would want to know if hosting my website with dockers on a VPS isn't a better idea ?

**I'm talking about the performances** (loading time, ect.), would it be faster on a VPS or a dedicated server ? Not really a price problem.

Most of my website are in Php/JS (Laravel).

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This question is off-topic, because it's not about programming. It's also impossible to answer, even if it were on topic, because there are too many variables.

Comment: @Flimzy I juste want to know if there is a big difference or if its more or less similar

Comment: You may want to know that. That doesn't mean there is an answer. (there isn't one). In some situations a VPS is faster. In some situations, shared hosing may be faster. In some cases, a dedicated server may be faster. In many cases, there won't be a noticeable difference between the three.

Comment: @Flimzy Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Shared Hosting means that others peoples sites runs in same virtual machine with yours. It's cheapest solution for smaller projects. But when other's page on that shared hosting hits hight traffic your page gets slow down as well.

Virtual Private Server means that you have your own machine but it's only virtual. It's good solution for bigger projects, like e-shops and some sites that hits some serious traffic.

Dedicated Server means that you have your own server and you can do whatever you want there (create smaller virtual servers or run without virtualization). It's also most expensive solution.

Some more [details here](https://hostingfacts.com/different-types-of-web-hosting/)

So answer to your question is VPS should be faster. But shared hosting can be fine as well. Personally i have several project that don't hit much traffic on a shared hosting and them run just good.